# Comparing two similar objects (holding same keys) and returning key value pairs that are different

Tags: javascript

I currently have two objects that look like the following:

```
   const initialValues= { name: "Robert Terrell", email: "billy@gmail.com" }
   const formData = { name: 'New Name', email: 'new email' }
```

I am attempting to compare the two objects with the same keys.  I would like to take the initialValues and use them as a reference to compare against the formData. If the formData has different values pertaining to a particular key I would like to return those key value pairs from formData.  in this case, both name: 'New Name' and email: 'new email' would be returned.  I'm having trouble really wrapping my mind around how to get into a deep comparison of the two objects.  I know I can loop through each object and grab their key value pairs using a for loop like so:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

but in regards to comparing the key value pairs I'm a bit stuck. any and all suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through one object, then compare its values with the corresponding element of the other.

```js
const initialValues= { name: "Robert Terrell", email: "billy@gmail.com" };
const formData = { name: 'New Name', email: 'new email' };
   
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(initialValues)) {
    if (value != formData[key]) {
        console.log(`${key}: ${value} != ${formData[key]}`);
    }
}
```